# creating distributions in mathematica

Tags: distribution, wolfram-mathematica, probability

I have a function which I know to be a multivariate distribution in (x,y), and mathematica is having numerical stability issues when I form the marginal distributions.

For example, marginalizing along y yields the following:
0.e^(154.88-0.5x^2)

Since I know the result must be a distribution, I would like to extract just the e^(-.5x^2) and do a renormalization myself. Alternatively, it would be even nicer if mathematica would let me take a multivariate function and somehow specify it as a probability distribution.

Anyway, does anyone know how to implement either of the above two solutions programatically?

Comment: It would be useful to see a more complete statement of the problem and your approach to solving it. 

However, remember that marginalising over a variable is achieved by integrating over it, which Mathematica should be able to do if you have an algebraic form for the density. Alternatively, it might be useful to think about marginalisation as as process in which you essentially pretend you never knew anything about the variable you want to marginalise over.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's an example of what I mean. Suppose I have the following 2D distribution:

```
Dist = 
3.045975040844157` E^(-(x^2/2) - y^2/
2) (-1 + E^(-1.` (x + 0.1` y) UnitStep[x + 0.1` y]))^2
```

And I attempt to

```
Integrate[Dist, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Mathematica does not provide an answer, or at least doesn't do so for quite a while on my computer. Suggestions?

Edit: ok, so it actually does, but takes 5 minutes on my Intel i5 with 4GB ram... I am still hoping theres some way to tap into Mathematica's built in distribution type (though it seems to be single variable only) and make use of their RandomReal[dist]. The best I could hope for is if Mathematica would let me specify this 2D function as a distribution, and be able to call RandomRealVector[dist].

Answer (score 1):

`ProbabilityDistribution` does take multivariate functions, though your Dist function is a bit too weird for its taste.

Additionaly, it seems that user-defined multivariate distributions currently don't work in combination with `RandomVariate` (the slightly more versatile V8 version of `RandomReal`/`RandomInteger`).  Univariate distributions work. I submitted a bug report to WRI.

Answer (score 1):

Well, dealing with symbolic expressions in Mathematica, it's best to keep things exact, ie avoid approximate numbers:

```
In[36]:= pdf = PiecewiseExpand[Rationalize[E^(-(x^2/2) - y^2/2)*
         (-1 + E^(-1.*(x + 0.1*y)*UnitStep[x + 0.1*y]))^2], 
  Element[{x, y}, Reals]]

Out[36]= Piecewise[{{E^(-2*x - x^2/2 - y/5 - y^2/2)*(-1 + 
       E^(x + y/10))^2, 10*x + y >= 0}}, 0]
```

In order to attack the problem, it is better to change variables:

```
In[56]:= cvr = 
 First[Solve[{10 x + y == u, (10 y - x)/101 == v}, {x, y}]]

Out[56]= {x -> (10 u)/101 - v, y -> u/101 + 10 v}
```

Notice that coefficients were chosen so that jacobian is a unity:

```
In[42]:= jac = Simplify[Det[Outer[D, {x, y} /. cvr, {u, v}]]]

Out[42]= 1
```

After the change of variables, you see that the density factorizes into a product:

```
In[45]:= npdf = FullSimplify[jac*pdf /. cvr]

Out[45]= Piecewise[{{E^(-(u/5) - u^2/202 - (101*v^2)/2)*(-1 + 
       E^(u/10))^2, u >= 0}}, 0]
```

That is, now variables 'u' and 'v' are independent. The 'v' variable is `NormalDistribution[0, 1/101]`, while the 'u' variable is a little more complicated, but can now be handled by `ProbabilityDistribution`.

```
In[53]:= updf = 
 Refine[npdf/nc, u >= 0]/PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[101]], v]

Out[53]= (E^(-(u/5) - u^2/202)*(-1 + E^(u/10))^2*Sqrt[2/(101*Pi)])/
   (1 - 2*E^(101/200)*Erfc[Sqrt[101/2]/10] + 
   E^(101/50)*Erfc[Sqrt[101/2]/5])
```

So you can now define the joint distribution for vector `{u,v}`:

```
dist = ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[0, 1/101], 
   ProbabilityDistribution[updf, {u, 0, Infinity}]];
```

Since the relationship between `{u,v}` and `{x,y}` is known, generating of `{x,y}` variates is easy:

```
XYRandomVariates[len_] := 
 RandomVariate[dist, len].{{-1, 10}, {10/101, 1/101}}
```

You can encapsulate the accumulated knowledge using `TransformedDistribution`:

```
origdist = 
  TransformedDistribution[{(10 u)/101 - v, 
    u/101 + 10 v}, {Distributed[v, NormalDistribution[0, 1/101]], 
    Distributed[u, ProbabilityDistribution[updf, {u, 0, Infinity}]]}];
```

E.g.:

```
In[68]:= Mean[RandomVariate[origdist, 10^4]]

Out[68]= {1.27198, 0.126733}
```